# Having Auto-increment on column in the context of another column

Tags: sqlite, database-design

I am developing a Point of Sale system where :

1. User can add items that's gonna be sold.
2. Each Sale Operation generate a recipe that memorize the sold item
3. The application makes a serial number for each sold product that increases by one each time that product is sold.

   E.g : I sold Product A & B, so each of one them get serial 1. Then I sold product A again, so it must get serial 2 while serial number of B still 1.

I got no clear idea how to implement this, but this is the schema design I made :

```
Recipe Table fields : id,created_at
Items Table fields : id,name,price
Association Table fields : id, Recipe_id, item_id, item_serial
```

I wonder if I can make item_serial auto increase depending on item_id. 

PS: SQLite is the used SQL back-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Table containing sequences for all items
CREATE TABLE serials (
    item_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Items(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    seq DEFAULT 1
);

-- Automatically add new serial entries for new items
CREATE TRIGGER serial_for_new_item AFTER INSERT ON Items
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO serials VALUES (new.id);
END;

-- Automatically set serials
CREATE TRIGGER update_seq AFTER INSERT ON Association
BEGIN
    UPDATE Association
       SET item_serial = (
                             SELECT seq
                               FROM serials
                              WHERE item_id = new.item_id
                         )
     WHERE id = new.id;

    UPDATE serials SET seq = seq + 1 WHERE item_id = new.item_id;
END;
```

Here's how it works:

- The `serials` table has single row for each item you have in `Items` table. It provides you with sequence numbers per item. It has a foreign key constraint, so it's bound to the `Items` table hardly. When you delete item from `Items`, then it's serial entry from `serials` will also be deleted (**remember to have foreign keys enabled in your SQLite connection**).
- The `serial_for_new_item` makes sure that when you insert new item into `Items` table, there will be a proper initial entry made in `serials` table.
- The `update_seq` trigger will automatically set proper serial number for every entry you insert into `Association` table. It also increments current serial number for recently inserted item association.

Basicly this will make everything automatically for you. You don't really need to write much more, just create those objects in database.

If you already had any entries in `Items` table you will have to populate `serials` table by yourself.